# Angular 4 : What to use instead of loadIntoLocation without destroying previous component?

Tags: angular, object, components

I have a json array which can contain either the component or the html selector for the component i want to load.

I am trying to load this data inside a for loop.

When I try to interpolate the value {{d.html}} it appears as plan text. When I use the innerHTML approach below and inspect the dom I see the html there but it does not behave as a custom component (the dom will just contain instead of initializing it and replacing it with the components template.

I have look at the dynamic content loader but that does not see to fit.

I would like to us loadIntoLocation  but that is depreciated.

What is the replacmment for loadIntoLocation.

On  (clic) I have a dropdown of the type of components that the user can select and I would like to load the component that they select.  The user can open several components at time so ngComponentOutlet I can use as is destroys any previous component.

```
    <div *ngFor="#item of componentslist" >
{{item.component | json}}
      <div [innerHTML]="item.html"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `DynamicComponentLoader` was removed a year ago. You can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` and adding another component won't destroy the previous ones. `innerHTML` doesn't result in components being created.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer I searching for an option to load the component in the place I tell it to. I am currently trying to use ViewContainerRef.createComponent() and you can create the component but I would like to assign the created component on the fly to a div that user clicks. So when you @ViewChild('theBody', {read: ViewContainerRef}) theBody; I trying to figure how to dynamically insert the string.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you way of doing I had created a ticket here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091044/angular-2-is-there-a-way-to-bind-a-hashtag-to-a-div/44091652#44091652 where I still stuck on how to assign he generated component to a div