# Angular 2: Is there a way to bind a hashtag to a div?

Tags: angular, data-binding, components

I am creating a component and injecting it. Is there instead of having a static reference to the #theBody to have it bind from an array or variable?

```
import {ComponentRef, Injectable, Component, Injector, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild,ComponentResolver} from '@angular/core';
import { HeroListComponent } from './hero-list.component';
```

If I got like #theBody predefined than I able to created

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button (click)="addCmp()" >add</button>
   <hero-list></hero-list>
   <div #theBody ></div>
  `,
  directives: [HeroListComponent]
})
```

But I would like to have injected so i could bind the component creation dynamically on the fly. So something like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button (click)="addCmp()" >add</button>

  <hero-list></hero-list>

   <div {{customtag}} ></div>
  `,
  directives: [HeroListComponent]
})
```

Where I define the #theBody in customtag.

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('theBody', {read: ViewContainerRef}) theBody;
  cmp:ComponentRef;

  customtag = '#theBody'

  constructor(injector: Injector,private resolver: ComponentResolver) {


    }

  addCmp(){
    console.log('adding');
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(HeroListComponent).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
      this.cmp = this.theBody.createComponent(factory);
      this.cmp.instance.test = "the test";
    });
  }
  }
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/RuwvwBOMK2IOXrhBQNPe?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<hero-list [customtag]='customtag'></hero-list>
```

And in hero-list.component:

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() customtag: String;
  constructor(private service: HeroService) { }

  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;
  test;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes = this.service.getHeroes();
  }

  selectHero(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

now you can use in HTML your #theBody in hero page.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and get an error
https://plnkr.co/edit/RuwvwBOMK2IOXrhBQNPe?p=preview

Comment: I'ts necessary add Input in hero-list.component.ts

`import { Component, OnInit, Input }   from '@angular/core';`

Comment: true, updated pink https://plnkr.co/edit/RuwvwBOMK2IOXrhBQNPe?p=preview